# Help me identify this character, it's a sticker

Tags: young-adult, character-identification

I need to identify this character:

[image]

Comment: http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Mask

Comment: I used Google's search-by-image function to turn up [this](http://bit.ly/1dBWVRB). It appears to be Mask, a D&D deity, like RhysW's link explains. In Chrome I can right-click on an image and select "search Google for this image" but that may be enabled by a plugin.

Comment: Post it as an answer, get upvotes.

Comment: I posted before your comment!   I promise!

Answer (score 10):

https://www.google.com/searchbyimage/upload

reveals this:

http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Mask

[image]

Apparently it is a character called Mask from Forgotten Realms.

Quoting from that site:

> Mask ..., the Lord of Shadows, is a loner god, most often associated with thieves or those of otherwise ill-repute.